# fetching with a predicate that checks a new instance dont work

Tags: ios, core-data, predicate

I am trying to fetch using the next predicate:

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"forPeople == %@", self.people];
```

When the people entity has a to-many relationship with the entity I am fetching.
The weird thing is that this predicate works perfectly on old instances of people, but when I create a new instance of people (and connect it to an instance of the fetched object) I get an empty fetchedObjects array.
but if I run the app again, the same predicate will give me a valid fetchedObjects array.

I specifically save and check the people new instance, so I dont know what makes the difference between the runs.

Comment: What is the type of self.people and forPeople here?Tell us a little more

Comment: self.people is an entity. and "forPeople" is a relationship from the fetched entity to the "people" entity

Comment: Are you using a common context? Or do you use multiple contexts?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you connect the enteties first,and then fetch it? Try to log the new **entety.forpPeople** after you create ir,maybe you just didn't connext it yet?

Comment: I loged it, and it is connected properly

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN forPeople", self.people];
```

Comment: forPeople is not a NSSet. The direction of the to-many relationship is that each DesiredNum (the fetched entity) has one forPeople, and each People has many DesiredNum. so as I understand, this predicate wont work

Comment: that naming convention confuses me quite a bit